# Can i sort the friendlist in a FBSDKAppInviteDialog for IOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use :

```
FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/myapplink"];
//optionally set previewImageURL
content.appInvitePreviewImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg"];

// present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
[FBSDKAppInviteDialog showWithContent:content
                         delegate:self];
```

Can i order the invitable friendlist in some way? It's an important feature for the app i'm developing, so if isn't possible to sort the friendlist, there is an alternative to FBSDKAppInviteDialog for invite friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not sort the list, it is sorted automatically by Facebook. If you want to build your own Invite flow you can use the [Invitable Friends](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/invitable_friends/) endpoint to get a list of friends you can invite and sort the list yourself and then send an [App Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app-request/) to the friends your user selected.

Please keep in mind though that the Invitable Friends endpoint is *only* available for Games.